# Prisma migrate on an altered DB

Tags: prisma

Given a team composed of data scientists and developers.

Developers want to use `schema.prisma` but data scientists don't and want to freely edit the DB directly...

What happen if a data scientist alter the DB directly? Will `prisma migrate dev/deploy` continue to work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the data scientists alter the database directly then there would be a drift between the prisma schema and the database schema.

So next time when someone invokes `prisma migrate dev` command, prisma would prompt you to reset the database.

From Documentation:

> The migrate dev command will prompt you to reset the database in the
> following scenarios:
>
> - Migration history conflicts caused by modified or missing migrations
> - The database schema has drifted away from the end-state of the migration history

It is advisable to stick to only one approach, either updating database only through migrations or just directly updating the database, combining both would lead to an undesirable state.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting! And what about `prisma migrate deploy` when a such drift exists?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Nurul Sundarani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71967841/133327), here is what I did:

```
$ vim .env # Points `DATABASE_URL` to the data-scientists' DB
$ npx prisma db pull # Pull changes from it and update `schema.prisma`

$ vim .env # Points `DATABASE_URL` back to localhost
$ npx prisma migrate dev # Generate the migration and apply changes tolocal DB
Name of your migration: my_sneaky_new_migration

$ git add prisma/schema.prisma prisma/migrations/20220603XXXXX_my_sneaky_new_migration
$ git commit

$ vim .env # Points `DATABASE_URL` to the data-scientists' DB
$ npx prisma migrate resolve --applied "my_sneaky_new_migration" # Mark the migration as already applied

$ vim .env # Points `DATABASE_URL` back to localhost
```